# Fluentlenium and cucumber tests not starting

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-junit, fluentlenium

I have a cucumber and fluentlenium project that doesn't start when i run the CucumberRunner. It just skips all the tests .I tried to find a solution on internet but didn't figured out the problem so far. A little bit of help would be nice.

This is are my steps:

```
public class LoginPageSteps extends BaseTest {

public LoginPageSteps() throws Exception {
    super();
}

@Page
LoginPage loginPage;


@Given("^I am on login page$")
public void goToLoginPage(){
    goTo(loginPage);
}

@When("^I enter username as '(.*?)'$")
public void enterUsername(String username) {
    waitAndFill(loginPage.username, username);
}

@And("^I enter password as '(.*?)'$")
public void enterPassword(String password)  {

    waitAndFill(loginPage.password, password);
    waitUntilCliclableAndClick(loginPage.loginButton);

}

@Then("^Login should be succesfull$")
public void checkLoginStatus()  {
    assertTrue(getDriver().getCurrentUrl().contains("login_attempt=1"));

}
}
```

This is my BaseTest.class :

```
  public class BaseTest extends FluentCucumberTest {

@Page
AccountPage accountPage;


@Before
public void before(Scenario scenario) {
    super.before(scenario);
}

@After
public void after(Scenario scenario) {
    super.after(scenario);
}

@Override
public WebDriver newWebDriver() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "../cucumber-test/src/test/resources/geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    return driver;
}

public void waitUntilCliclableAndClick(FluentWebElement element) {
    await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(element).clickable();
    element.click();
}

public void waitAndFill(FluentWebElement element, String data) {
    await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(element).displayed();
    element.fill().with(data);
}



}
```

And this is my feature file :

```
   Feature: valid-login 

Scenario: 
   Given I am on login page 
   When I enter username as "myusername"
   And I enter password as "mypassword" 
   Then Login should be succesfull
```

And this is the runner :

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@CucumberOptions(features={"src/test/resources/features"})
public class CucumberRunner {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Cucumber runner is called `CucumberRunner`

This may be an issue if you build using Maven. The testrunner in Maven, Surefire, searches for classes named `XXXXTest` or `TestXXXX`. Your runner class will not be found.

Try to rename your Cucumber runner to `CucumberRunnerTest` and see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [example project](https://github.com/FluentLenium/fluentlenium-cucumber) which might be helpful to you.

Although I've cloned / ran this example project, the cucumber version was old and needed an update.

Here's what I've done to make the project work:

Updated `fluentlenium-cucumber`, `fluentlenium-assertj` to `3.3.0`, `cucumber-core`, `cucumber-junit`, `cucumber-java`, `cucumber-picocontainer` to `1.2.5` as well as `junit` and `htmlunit-driver` to the latest versions in `pom.xml`.

Step file looks like this:

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import org.fluentlenium.adapter.cucumber.FluentCucumberTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BasicStep extends FluentCucumberTest {

    @Before
    public void before(Scenario scenario) {

    }

    @Override
    public WebDriver newWebDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/geckodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        return driver;
    }

    @Given("I open Google")
    public void iOpenGoogle() {
        this.initFluent(new newWebDriver());
        goTo("http://google.com");

        await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertThat(window().title()).contains("Google");
    }

    @After
    public void after(Scenario scenario){
        super.after(scenario);
    }
  }
```

And the test file:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/toto")

public class BasicTest {

}
```

New test result:

[image]

Hope you get it working!

Comment: What version of cucumber have you used ?

Comment: Seems to be am old version of cucumber from the example project. Will investigate / update the example project and come back to you.

Comment: I tried your scenario and it works but in my case it doesnt because i can't call  getDriver() in @Before because it is null at the runtime. I want to override newWebDriver() method and set the driver there instead of the Before because i only want to run one time. Calling in Before will initialize the driver again when my other tests are run.

Comment: @T.Frincu, you can leave the `before` empty and in the first step just add `this.initFluent(newWebDriver());`. I managed to make this work in the Example project (updated the answer)